# How to set the empty cell for numerical type in NPOI

Tags: c#, excel

I use NPOI to create an excel file. If the cell is numeric, the code to write the cell is

```
  row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(Runtime);
```

because there is one only function to set the value of cell. But if Runtime is missing, and use SetCellValue(""), then the cell type is string and is no longer numeric. When read by

```
GetCell(cell, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).NumericCellValue
```

it returns an exception:

```
"Can not get numerical value from text cell."
```

So how to write the cell in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
cell.SetCellType( CellType.Numeric);
```

before assignment

Comment: Yes, after cell.SetCellType( CellType.Numeric), the cell is set to 0 even without SetCellValue(Runtime);